# 6 power favor tile Town/Culture benefit order

Tags: terra-mystica

In the middle of a game I built a temple which let me pick a favor tile. I selected the favor tile that lets you form a town with 6 power. This favor tile also awards you 2 of the red cultures.

It just so happened that when I pulled the tile I was 2 moves away on the red culture track from being at the top, AND after pulling the favor tile I had 4 structures that that netted 6 power meaning I now had enough to form a town.

I was playing a two player game and the person I was playing with and I didn't know if I should be allowed to move my red culture piece up 2 since my 4 structures with 6 power were now enough to form a town. We wondered if the 2 red cultures had to be taken first, then the town formed next.

We decided that I should form the town first, then move the culture piece up 2. Please let me know if this was correct OR if I should have been forced to move the culture first (meaning I could only use 1 of the 2 bonuses) then form the town next.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if a Town would be founded by taking this tile, you get the key immediately, and may use it to reach 10 on the Fire Cult with the 2 Fire influence.

> we see that founding a town is not an active action you have to execute but happens automatically and instantly when the conditions are met.
>   and by taking the favor tile(s) the conditions have been met.
>   thus in the same moment you have a town and are allowed to advance to level 10 with the cult bonus shown on your favor tile(s).

(source: http://boardgamegeek.com/article/10450352#10450352)